# How to reload another jqgrid in load complete of jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using `jqgrid v 4.4.4`. How to reload another Jqgrid in loadComplete of another jqgrid?.

I try this code

```
 loadComplete: function () {
        debugger;
        var ids = jQuery("#FiTAList").getDataIDs();
        var len = ids.length,
            newLine;
        if (len < 5) {
            AddNewRowToGrid(len, "#FiTAList");
        }

        ReloadFItaTimeInOut(163);
      }


function ReloadFItaTimeInOut(id) {
var gridId = "#FiTATimeList";
$(gridId).setGridParam({
    datatype: 'json',
    url: '../Request/GetFitaTime?&FAId=' + id,
    page: 1
}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

but it's not hitting my controller to reload the data. Did I do wrong or my syntax is wrong?.

Comment: Have you tried moving the function ReloadFItaTimeInOut() above the loadComplete function?

Comment: @iCode what do you by above the loadComplete function?.

Comment: Actually copy and paste the ReloadFltaTimeInOut() function above the loadComplete() function so that it occurs first in the file and gets parsed first. I was just guessing since I don't even know if your functions are in the same script file.

Comment: @iCode i tried it. but still the same. as i notice after the loadComplete that has my reload code. if i force to reload the grid using the pager and its hitting my controller and its giving the parameter that i set.